# Writing unit tests for Java 8 streams

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito

I have a list and I'm streaming this list to get some filtered data as:

```
List<Future<Accommodation>> submittedRequestList = 
    list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .map(config -> taskExecutorService.submit(() -> requestHandler
                 .handle(jobId, config))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When I wrote tests, I tried to return some data using a `when()`:

```
List<Future<Accommodation>> submittedRequestList = mock(LinkedList.class);
when(list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                  .map(config -> executorService.submit(() -> requestHandler
                            .handle(JOB_ID, config))).collect(Collectors.toList())).thenReturn(submittedRequestList);
```

I'm getting `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
LinkedList$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$716dd84d cannot be returned by submit()` error. How may I resolve this error by using a correct `when()`?

Comment: It really makes no sense to mock streams. There is a rule that you shouldn't mock what doesn't belongs to you. Implementation can be a change in some time, and a test will fail because you are not testing behavior but specifics. 
Imagine, how do you write this test if you want to write a test first? Will you assume that you HAVE to use stream there?

Comment: Also, why are you mocking a *`LinkedList`*? Just use a real implementation. `new LinkedList<>()`. Boom, done. Behaves entirely correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only mock single method calls, not entire fluent interface cascades.

Eg, you could do

```
Stream<Future> fs = mock(Stream.class);
when(requestList.stream()).thenReturn(fs);
Stream<Future> filtered = mock(Stream.class);
when(fs.filter(Objects::nonNull).thenReturn(filtered);
```

and so on.

IMO it's really not worth mocking the whole thing, just verify that all filters were called and check the contents of the result list.